# How to use PermissionRequiredMixin in FBV?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am thinking about how I can use **PermissionRequiredMixin** in FBV.(I have used the same in CBV and it is working as expected).
Please find the FBV(here need to implement permission). I don't want to use @login_required()

> @login_required()
> This will check only if the user is authenticated or not.

```
def delete_viewgen(request,PermissionRequiredMixin,id):
    oneuser=ShiftChange.objects.get(id=id)
    permission_required = ('abc.add_shiftchange',)
    oneuser.delete()# delete
    return redirect('/gensall')
```

I am getting ERROR :  missing 1 required positional argument: 'PermissionRequiredMixin'

**CBV** Case where it is working fine.

```
class ShiftChangeUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    permission_required = ('abc.change_shiftchange',)
    login_url = '/login/'
    model=ShiftChange
    fields='__all__'
```

In *CBV* it is working fine and if user is not having change permission it is giving **403 Forbidden** how to implement same in *FBV* and also how to customize *403 Forbidden* message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On function based views you would use decorators, in your particular case
[`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator

```
@permission_required('abc.change_shiftchange', raise_exception=True)
delete_viewgen(request,id)
```

Comment: Thanks! @iklinac 
If the user is not having permission to delete it is redirecting to the login page instead of giving 403 Forbidden.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/deletegen/2700588704/